# apply function in Python throws the error - object not iterable

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting an error while applying a function. For each condition, I am supposed to refer to the previous row values and also the next values while present in the current row. If i have more than one reference of previous row values, then it is giving an error. Please advise how do i fix this in a different way.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'B': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define a custom function that uses values from the previous and next rows
def process_row(row):
    previous_row = df.shift(1).loc[row.name]
    next_row = df.shift(-1).loc[row.name]
    
    # Access values from previous and next rows
    prev_value_A = previous_row['A']
    prev_value_B = previous_row['B']
    next_value_A = next_row['A']
    next_value_B = next_row['B']
    
    # Perform  calculations using previous and next values
    result = {}
    result['x'] = ((prev_value_B - prev_value_A) - (next_value_B - next_value_A))
    
    return result

# Apply the function to each row in the DataFrame
df = df.apply(process_row, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use a function and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for that, directly vectorize your calculation with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
s = df['B']-df['A']

df['x'] = s.shift()-s.shift(-1)
```

Output:

```
   A   B    x
0  1   6  NaN
1  1   7 -2.0
2  1   8 -2.0
3  1   9 -2.0
4  1  10  NaN
```